# Change order status with AJAX in plugin wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am customizing a plugin, which gives recent orders and plays a sound notification. However i want to add an ajax call to a custom button that shows in every row:

This is my method so far:

```
    // ajax function in plugin file
    <?php 
function my_action_javascript($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // returns correct order id in every button
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">             // initiate script
        jQuery(function($){ 

            $('pluginchangebutton').click( function(e){
            e.preventdefault();


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                    data: {
                        'action': 'my_action', // send php function ? 
                        'order_id': <?php echo $order_id; ?>, // Here we send the order Id
                    },

                     success: function(response) { // no response at all
                    alert('ok');
            },
            error: function(response) { // no response at all
                alert('error');
            }
                });
            });
        });
        </script> <?php
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );// register my_action to wp ajax
        function my_action() {
        if ( isset($_POST['order_id']) && $_POST['order_id'] > 0 ) {       
            $order = wc_get_order($_POST['order_id']); 
            $order->update_status('completed');      // function to update status
            die();
        }
    }
    // ajax end
```

This is the ajax function which i place on top of the plugin file.

And this is how i display my table:

```
// get recent orders
 $recent_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'limit' => $show_order_num,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'status' => $show_order_statuses,
    ));

    $content = "<h1>Нови порачки</h1>";
    $content .= "<table id='customers-new-order-notification'>";
    $content .= "<tr><th>Последни порачки</th></tr>";
    $content .= "<tr><th>Порачка бр.</th><th>Дата на порачка</th><th>Статус на порачка</th><th>Детали за порачка</th></tr>";
    

    foreach ($recent_orders as $recent_order) {
        // get order details .. ... .. .. .. .. ..
        $order_id = $recent_order->get_id();
        $_order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order_date = $_order->get_date_created();
        $order_status = $recent_order->get_status();
        $order_link = get_site_url();
        $order_link .= "/wp-admin/post.php?post=";
        $order_link .= $order_id;
        $order_link .= "&action=edit";
        $billing_first_name_plugin =  $recent_order->get_billing_first_name();
        $billing_address_1_plugin =  $recent_order->get_billing_address_1();
        $billing_city_plugin       = $recent_order->get_billing_city();
        $billing_postalcode_plugin = $recent_order->get_billing_postcode();
        $billing_email_plugin  = $recent_order->get_billing_email();
        $billing_phone_plugin  = $recent_order->get_billing_phone();
        $billing_country_plugin    = $recent_order->get_billing_country();
        $order_shipping_method_plugin = $recent_order->get_shipping_method() . ' - ' . $recent_order->get_shipping_total() . ' rsd';
        $order_get_subtotal_plugin = $recent_order->get_subtotal() . ' rsd';
        $order_get_total_plugin =  $recent_order->get_total() . ' rsd';
        $order_javena='Непотврдена';
        $customer_note_plugin = $recent_order->get_customer_note();
        $statusPrefix = "wc-";
        $_orderStatus = $statusPrefix . $order_status;
        $_order_status = $order_status_map[$_orderStatus];
        
        $date_format = get_option('date_format'); // format 
        $time_format = get_option('time_format'); // format 

        $format_order_date = $time_format . " - " . $date_format;
        $items = $recent_order->get_items(); // get product items from order 
        
        // add content to $content .. table .. .. . .. row 1

        // .... .... ... ... ... ... ... ... row 2

        // row 3 start
        $content .= "<td>" . esc_html($order_javena) ."<br>";
        $content .= my_action_javascript($_order) . "<button class=pluginchangebutton type=submit>Потврди</button>";
        $content .="</td>"; // row 3 end
        // row 4 add .. .. .. 
        // row 4 end
        if (!$isNew) {
        delete_option('_new_order_id_for_notification');
        $time = $refreshTime;
        header("Refresh:" . esc_html($time) . "");
        add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
        
    }
    echo $content;
}
```

In inspecting, the **$.ajax** gets the **correct order id** for every button, however i do not get a response at all. I've tried with console.log as well but still, no response.
I have tried inserting type, datatype and url with ' ', as well as " ", still nothing.
This code is in the plugin file.
I have tried adding it to functions.php, it does not work.
Can i get some guidance?

Comment: Can you tell me where do you place this function customer_completes_order_thankyou? Do you see the JS code and the HTML code written in this function on page?

Comment: @Vantiya Yes, so i've tried putting it at top of the file. ( in plugin directory )
The html code shows the buttons and the js code gives the correct order id.

Comment: Ok. Please also ensure that AJAX is also being called correctly. Your code looks like correct.

Comment: Do you have any other customization along with that like on status change are you customizing email template? Is there any error with that code?

Comment: @Vantiya no not at all, no status change customization. However i do not know what to hook it to

Comment: @Vantiya i have updated my post

Comment: well, then code looks ok to me. If you can share the URL I may check it tomorrow morning.